# Python3 - Como voltar pasta?

Tags: python-3.x

Meu arquivo **main.py** está no diretório raiz do meu projeto, exemplo:

```
"C:\Projetos\PyValidacao\main.py"
```

Com o módulo `os` consigo pegar o caminho real do **main.py**, porém preciso fazer com que crie uma pasta dentro de `"C:\Projetos"`. O problema é que eu não consigo fazer ele voltar para a pasta a partir da raiz do projeto.

Como é que se faz para voltar o diretório com o módulo `os` ? Há algo melhor para esse fim ?

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver usando a função "abspath" da seguinte forma:

```
return os.path.abspath(r"..\")
```

Dessa maneira voltou um diretório como eu queria.

Comment: Já ia falar pra você usar "..", legal!

Comment: Cleber, lembre-se que o `"\"` serve para caracteres especiais. Então coloque mais uma barra para não gerar problemas no seu código.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 com o prefixo `r` na string não é necessário

Comment: Não vi o prefixo kkk Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Existe essa gambiarra aqui:

```
diretorio = os.getcwd() #Pega o diretório atual
num = diretorio.rfind("\\") + 1 #Acha onde tem a ultima "\"
os.chdir(diretorio[:num]) #Volta o diretório
```

Pronto, isso funciona no Windows.